# How to add forced water radiator?

Tags: heating, baseboard

I have a very small cast iron radiator which works great, but when really cold temperature hits outside, it is not enough to heat that particular room (and it is on the third floor so 2nd zone is not an option now).

I want to add baseboard radiator to run along the side of the wall next to cast iron radiator. Given that small radiator is sufficient 80% of the time, I would like to be able to shut off baseboard one and turn it on only when needed.

How can I connect both?  And what type of shut off valve to use for baseboard one?

Comment: Why do you believe that you want to be able to turn the new radiator off?

Comment: If you really want to turn off the second one, make it an electric.  This has the advantage that you can set the standalone electric baseboard's thermostat to whatever you want, and the room will be better controlled than it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I would call a bunch of heating guys and scrap dealers in your neighbor hood and see if you can buy another small cast iron radiator. Pipe the two in series and add a thermostatic valve (Danfoss or Honeywell) to the first radiator. It can replace the shut off valve if you have one. Then you would have automatic operation and would not have to rig up any thing else. Hot water is piped in at the top out at the bottom. The rad does not have to match the other rad ,just make sure it has connection nipples on the top and bottom just like the existing rads